# Primes Not Dividing $\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let $n \geq 3$, show ${2n \choose n}$ is not divisible by $p$ for all primes $\frac{2n}{3} <p\leq n$

Note: This fact along with other facts about ${2n \choose n}$ are used in a proof of Bertrand's postulate.

Comment: A proof of that fact is contained in [this proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate) of Bertrand’s postulate.

Comment: Any such prime appears exactly twice both in the numerator and the denominator of $\binom{2n}{n}= \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the idea is rather simple (not verifying Brian's hint...) :

We need to divide $(2n)!$ by $n!^2$ so let's write the primes of the decomposition of $(2n)!$ and $n!$.

Let's suppose that $\frac n2<p \le n$ is such a prime larger than $2$ then :

$$
\binom{2n}{n} =
\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=
\frac{
2n\cdot (2n-1)\cdots(2p)\cdots (n)\cdots (p)\cdots 2\cdot 1}
{(n)\cdots (p)\cdots 2\cdot 1\cdot (n)\cdots (p)\cdots 2\cdot 1}
$$

When $3p\le 2n$ we will have at least $3$ $p$'s at the top and the fraction will be divisible by $p$ else the two $p$ will cancel !